# Making a color mixing game: If you click red and yellow what command can I use to make the color turn orange?

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

I'm using python with turtle and I have 3 paint tubes drawn: red, yellow, and blue. Each tube has a button you click and the bowl underneath changes color as if you're "mixing" the colors. I already having clicking red making the bowl turn red (along with the other colors) but now I need some sort of command or statement so that if you click the red tube and then you click the yellow tube, the bowl will turn orange. I have no idea where to go about this, each of the 3 tubes has its own turtle.

I have functions for making the bowl red, yellow, and red. 
I also have a function for making the bowl orange.
BUT if there is actually a command I don't know about where you can mix colors or a "if clicked" command I would use that.

Please help! Deadline: April 25

## Example of one of my functions:

```
def redColor(x, y):
  red.hideturtle()
  red.tracer(0,0)
  red.seth(0)
  red.goto(-140,-80)
  red.pd()
  red.fillcolor('red')

  red.begin_fill()
  red.pensize(1)
  red.fd(280)
  red.rt(135)
  red.fd(66)
  red.rt(45)
  red.fd(190)
  red.rt(45)
  red.fd(66)
  red.end_fill()
  red.update()
```

## Example of On Screen Click Commands:

```
red.onclick(redColor)
ylw.onclick(ylwColor)
blue.onclick(blueColor)
```

Comment: This question is confusing. Please ask a `reproducible` question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Show what you tried, where you failed. Don't just post a project requirement and simply ask for help

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Python represents the color using the [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model): For each color, it stores the intensity of its **R**ed, **G**reen and **B**lue component. It allows 256 possible values for each component (from 0 to 255), so 256 shades of red, 256 shades of green and 256 shades of blue. This allows for a combined 256*256*256 = ~16 Million colors.

You can try this [online RGB mixer](https://csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/rgb-mixer/) (link taken from the Wikipedia site) to get a feel for this color model.

For example, (255,0,0) would be maximum red intensity, no green and no blue, so this gives you a full red color. Whereas (255,255,0) is maximum red and green intensity with no blue, which results in the color yellow.

To mix two such RGB colors, you can simply take the average of each component. So when mixing full red (255,0,0) with yellow (255,255,0), the average of the red components would be (255+255)/2 = 255, the average of the green components would be (0+255)/2 = ~128 and the average of the blue components would be (0+0)/2 = 0.

There is also an alternative representation where the intensity of each component is represented as a value between 0.0 and 1.0, instead of 0 to 255. So in this representation, full red would be (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) and yellow would be (1.0, 1.0, 0.0). Orange would then again be the average of each component, that is (1.0, 0.5, 0.0). It doesn't really matter which one you use, but in our case the 0.0-1.0 representation is easier because we do not have to worry about rounding when taking the average.

To use this with your turtles, you have to take two steps:

- Switch the screen to use the 0.0-1.0 color representation with `screen.colormode(1.0)` ([reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode)).
- Set the color of your turtle with `fillcolor((1.0,0.0,0.0))` instead of `fillcolor('red')`.  When you call `fillcolor()` on your turtle, it will then give you the RGB representation ([reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.fillcolor)).

Putting it all together:

```
import turtle

# Use the 0.0-1.0 color model instead of the 0-255 one
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.colormode(1.0)

red_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
red_turtle.fillcolor((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))

yellow_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
yellow_turtle.fillcolor((1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

# Get the RGB values of the red and yellow turtle
r1,g1,b1 = red_turtle.fillcolor()
r2,g2,b2 = yellow_turtle.fillcolor()

# Take the average of each component, resulting in orange
r3 = (r1 + r2) / 2.0
g3 = (g1 + g2) / 2.0
b3 = (b1 + b2) / 2.0

orange_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
orange_turtle.fillcolor((r3, g3, b3))

turtle.done()
```